# Generic Method to Save and Retrieve List of Custom Objects in Shared Preference

Tags: android, object, gson, sharedpreferences

There are many SO question asked related to this topic but all discuss specific Type of Custom object List storing or retrieving in shared prefs,

But my question is about how to store any kind of Object List in shared prefs:

**My Attempt(almost same as in [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo)):**

**Store:**

```
public void putListObject(String key, ArrayList<Object> objArray){
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        ArrayList<String> objStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Object obj : objArray){
            objStrings.add(gson.toJson(obj));
        }
        preferences.edit().putString(key, objStrings).apply();
    }
```

**Get**

```
public List<Object> getListObject(String key, Class<?> mClass){
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 

        List<String> objStrings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(preferences.getString(key, ""), "‚‗‚")));
        List<Object> objects =  new ArrayList<Object>();

        for(String jObjString : objStrings){
            Object value  = gson.fromJson(jObjString,  mClass);
            objects.add(value);
        }
        return objects;
    }
```

Problem in the above code is, **it stores value in shared prefs** , but cannot get it back as expected.

**Expected Behavior:**

```
class myClass{
  int i;
}

List<myClass> mc = new ArrayList();

// Store:

putListObject("KEY",mc);


// GET:

List<myClass> tr = getListObject("KEY",myClass.class); // error here
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getListObject` method, you're returning a List of plain Object whereas tr in this line `List<myClass> tr = getListObject("KEY",mc.myClass.class);` accepts List of myClass objects.

Comment: it was typo sorry , its `myClass.class`

Comment: I understand it'd be `List<myClass> tr = getListObject("KEY", myClass.class);` Can you tell me what's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with TinyDB implementation, but I was able to resolve the getListObject and putListObject as follows:

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> getListObject(String key, Class<T> mClass){
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ArrayList<String> objStrings = getListString(key);
    ArrayList<T> objects =  new ArrayList<T>();

    for(String jObjString : objStrings){
        T value  = gson.fromJson(jObjString,  mClass);
        objects.add(value);
    }
    return objects;
}

public <T> void putListObject(String key, ArrayList<T> objArray){
    checkForNullKey(key);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> objStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(T obj : objArray){
        objStrings.add(gson.toJson(obj));
    }
    putListString(key, objStrings);
}
```

Notice I used generics  instead of type Object.

Hope this helps!